# Python+Pandas+Dataframe+CSV : Code removes all rows from a dataframe instead of specified ones

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have written a code to remove all the rows which have NaNs in category_id column which successfully removed the rows with NaNs in category_id column:

```
   #removal of rows in dataframe that have NaN values in 'category_id' column

   #data = data[np.isfinite(data['category_id'])]
   data = data[data['category_id'].notnull()]

   print(data['category_id'].shape)
   data.to_csv('dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
   print(type(data['category_id']))
```

Output:

```
(778,)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Next, I wrote a code to retain all the rows which have only values specified in a list:

```
#selecting rows of the dataset whose 'category' column has values mentioned in a list


category_ids = [19, 22, 2, 30, 23]
data = data[data.category_id.isin(category_ids)]
print(data.shape) 

data.to_csv('dataset.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Output:

```
(0, 164)
```

So, it produces empty dataframe and CSV. Why?

Comment: Can you create sample data?

Comment: Did you mean you wanted to see sample data from that dataframe?

Comment: Are values in column integers or strings? What return `print (data.category_id.dtype)` ?

Comment: my idea too, looks like you have strings in your df and try to compare them with ints - this way, nothing is found and your df is empty

Comment: @jezrael : object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is your data are strings, not integers in column `category_id`.

```
print (data.category_id.dtype)
object
```

So need convert values in list to strings:

```
category_ids = ['19', '22', '2', '30', '23']
data = data[data.category_id.isin(category_ids)]
```

Or convert column to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
category_ids = [19, 22, 2, 30, 23]
data = data[data.category_id.astype(int).isin(category_ids)]
```

Comment: @Debbie - Then need `data = data[pd.to_numeric(data.category_id, errors='coerce').isin(category_ids)]`, it seems some non numeric values or not parseable values